# How to display object from firebase on asp.net core mvc website?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm making a website in asp.net core MVC, where I should be able to display the stock of merchandise.

I made a firebase real-time database where I should be able to add more merchandise and display the merchandise on the website. I am now able to write to the database to add merchandise and it is added properly. My problem is that I am not able to get the data correctly from the database.

**This is inside the HomeController:**

```cs
Merchandise test = new Merchandise("Løbsmærker", 25, test2);

var firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient("https://invictuslagerstyring.firebaseio.com/");
var result = await firebaseClient.Child("Name " + test.Name).PostAsync(test);

var ud = await firebaseClient.Child("Name " + test.Name).Child("Name").OnceAsync<Merchandise>();
```

**This is the merchandise constructor:**

```cs
public Merchandise(String name, double salePrice, Boolean[] size)
{
    merchID = ++amountOfMerch;
    this.name = name;
    this.salePrice = salePrice;
    this.size = new Boolean[size.Length];

    if (size.Length > 0)
    {
        this.size = new Boolean[amountOfSizes];
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

I expect the output "Løbsmærker" but the actual output is `Firebase.Database.FirebaseObject1[Lagerstyring.Controllers.Merchandise][]`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that after you run:

```
var ud = await firebaseClient.Child("Name " + test.Name).Child("Name").OnceAsync<Merchandise>();
```

you assign above variable to text field or something. Which invokes `ToString()` method. Instead create a new variable and assign `Name` to it.

Comment: I assign it to a message displayed on the website like this: `ViewData["Message"] = ud.ToString();`

Now I'm getting an error saying: `ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.String,Lagerstyring.Controllers.Merchandise].`